# How to map Chain in Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have table that has columns :
id, parent_id.

And I want to have chain of rows like:
1, null
2, 1
3, 2
4, 3

Is it possible make ORM XML mapping with Doctrine,
that give fields for Entity  
"private Collection $parents"
"private Collection $children".
If entity's Id is 4, then i will have Entities with Ids (1,2,3) in field parents.
If entity's Id is 1, then i will have Entities with Ids (2,3,4) in field children.

In usual way it looks like this, but This will not work :

```
<one-to-many field="children" target-entity="SomeEntity" mapped-by="parent"/>

<many-to-one field="parent" target-entity="SomeEntity" inversed-by="children">
  <join-columns>
    <join-column/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
```